# Extract Specific Part of $_GET variable or the URL itself

Tags: php

got this thing users comes to my site and they have variable in the url new every time but the ending is the same always 
/dp/Random ID/

```
http://mywebsite.com/?source=text&keyword=site.com/random-text/dp/10505/
```

So what I'm trying to save is /dp/this id/ i thought about using something like:

```
  $keywword = $_GET['keyword'];
```

And some how to extract the random ID like in regex you can find what is between /dp/ and / and save to variable like $id to be able to use it later on.

Comment: I would say you need to start with a valid url. Spaces are not allowed in the query string so if your random text has these or other non-allowed characters, whatever way you choose is likely to break.

Comment: @jeroen this was my own change the text has - so it's my fault! didn't knew that :)

Comment: If your query sting is properly encoded, you can use any of the first two solutions.

Comment: @jeroen what will be a better choice my website is heavy in sense on performance?

Comment: String (or array) functions will almost always beat regex but you'd have to test that as you need multiple functions as opposed to only one regex.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
$keyword = $_GET['keyword'];
$foo     = explode('/', $keyword);
$id      = $foo[3];
```

[<kbd>DEMO:</kbd> http://codepad.org/CcOcwDa6](http://codepad.org/CcOcwDa6)

---

I was also going to suggest a regExp solution:

```
preg_match('/dp\/([^\/]+)\//', $url, $matches);
$id = $matchs[1];
```

The nice thing about the regExp solution is that if your `keyword` parameter ever changes, this should still work as long as the id you're looking for is preceded by `dp/`.

[<kbd>DEMO:</kbd> http://ideone.com/xqXU2b](http://ideone.com/xqXU2b)

Comment: This is nice! So this is like checking for the third "/" and gives back everything after it? what about the last one? the results will look like this? 10505/ or 10505 (I need without /)

Comment: It turns the value of `$_GET['keyword']` into an array of values delimited by `/`; in this case, 10505 is the value. Since `/` is the delimiter, `$foo[3]` should not show up as `10505/`, but `10505`. If you do find yourself needing to remove characters, you can use [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php).

Answer (score 5):

Or with regex:

```
if (preg_match('/^.*\/dp\/([0-9]+)\/?$/i', $_GET['keyword'], $matches))
    var_dump($matches[1]);
```

Comment: I can see you got 0-9 this means it will not detect letters? I'm sorry I have included only numbers but sometimes they got Letter like A1512B23 it's random :)

Comment: @MarkVoidale In that case, you can replace `[0-9]+` with `\w+`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will do the trick:

```
$keyword = $_GET['keyword'];
$id = preg_replace('#^(?:.+)?\/dp\/([0-9]+)\/(?:.+)?$#', '$1', $keyword);
```

Comment: I can see you got 0-9 this means it will not detect letters? I'm sorry I have included only numbers but sometimes they got Letter like A1512B23 it's random :)

Comment: If you have letters, just change `[0-9]` by `[a-z0-9]`. This will give you: `$id = preg_replace('#^(?:.+)?\/dp\/([a-z0-9]+)\/(?:.+)?$#i', '$1', $keyword);` (I added the option `i` after the `#` because of the possible case)